# Output R dataframe to SAS format Issue

Tags: r, sas

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
df_dummy = data.frame(
  Company=c("0001","0002","0003","0004","0005"),
  Measure=c("A","B","C","D","E"),
  Num=c(10,10,10,10,10),
  Den=c(20,20,20,20,20),
  Rate=c(50.0,50.0,50.0,50.0,50.0)
)

df_dummy$Company <- as.character(df_dummy$Company)
df_dummy$Measure <- as.character(df_dummy$Measure)
```

I am using this to export to an .xpt file

```
write.xport(df_dummy, file = "data/tmp.xpt")
lookup.xport("data/tmp.xpt")
```

In SAS, I use this code to import:

```
libname sasfile 'PATH\data';
libname xptfile xport 'PATH\data\tmp.xpt' access=readonly;
proc copy inlib=xptfile outlib=sasfile;
run;
```

The table looks fine, but the rate doesn't show the decimal point.

In my actual dataset, there are a lot more rows but it's the same format essentially and if I run a lookup.xport I get this:

```
Variables in data set `MEASURES':
  dataset    name      type format flength fdigits iformat iflength ifdigits label  nobs
 MEASURES   ID character              0       0                0        0       29064
 MEASURES MEASURE character              0       0                0        0       29064
 MEASURES     NUM   numeric              0       0                0        0       29064
 MEASURES     DEN   numeric              0       0                0        0       29064
 MEASURES    RATE   numeric              0       0                0        0       29064
```

However, if I use the same SAS code to import this, I get something that looks completely off and I can't figure out what's causing it.

[image]

Comment: Maybe try the `write_xpt`-function from the `haven`-package?

Comment: If I use the write_xpt function, SAS cannot recognize it and gives me an error that it's not a SAS data set.

Comment: Ended up using the Foreign package, as xpt files don't seem to be reliable when exported from R.

Comment: Not seeing the decimals in SAS is merely a format issue. If it's the only problem then it's quite easy to fix, unless data has been corrupted along the way. Just use `format rate 6.2;` in a data step.

Comment: Up until the last screen shot you had not described anything that appeared to be a problem. Numbers are just numbers and the way they display are up to the programmer. If you want to print your integer values with a .0 after them then attach a format like `F4.1` and SAS will display it that way.  Not sure what that last screen shot was from but it looks like the data got corrupted.  Did you transfer the files as a text file instead of as a binary file between an PC and other system?

Comment: The last screen shot is what the data looks like if I import the R exported xpt file in SAS.  I set the output to a network drive - I'm not sure if that would corrupt the data but the file itself was not transferred between anything.

Comment: @Tom is asking if you moved the file from a Unix to Windows or vice versa essentially.

Comment: Did you try PROC CIMPORT instead of PROC COPY?

Comment: No the file was not moved to or copied to another computer or changed OS, but it was saved on a Network drive.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot replicate your issue using R (3.4.1) and SAS (9.4 TS1M4) on Mac OS X with both being 64 bit versions. The 32/64 bit versions can cause issues sometimes. 
I used R Studio and SAS UE, both freely available for education usage.

Full R code:

```
install.packages("SASxport")

library("SASxport")

df_dummy = data.frame(
  Company=c("0001","0002","0003","0004","0005"),
  Measure=c("A","B","C","D","E"),
  Num=c(10,10,10,10,10),
  Den=c(20,20,20,20,20),
  Rate=c(50.0,50.0,50.0,50.0,50.0)
)

df_dummy$Company <- as.character(df_dummy$Company)
df_dummy$Measure <- as.character(df_dummy$Measure)

write.xport(df_dummy, file = "tmp.xpt")
```

Full SAS Code:

```
libname sasfile '/folders/myfolders/';
libname xptfile xport '/folders/myfolders/tmp.xpt' access=readonly;
proc copy inlib=xptfile outlib=sasfile;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example works. Even with older version or R. Make sure your transport file had not been corrupted by transferring between machines.  A transport file is binary data with fixed length 80 byte records, but much of data looks like ASCII codes.

SAS transport files follow the SAS V5 rules for names. Make sure that your member name and variable names are valid SAS names and are not longer than 8 characters. Character variables cannot be longer than 200 characters.

You can quickly look at the file using a simple data step. Especially for your small example. So if you see that the length is not exactly a multiple of 80 or you see that the header records do not start at the beginning of an 80 byte record then something has corrupted the file.

```
 56         data _null_;
 57           infile '/test/tmp.xpt' lrecl=80 recfm=f ;
 58           input;
 59           list;
 60         run;

 NOTE: The infile '/test/tmp.xpt' is:
       Filename=/test/tmp.xpt,
       Owner Name=xxxxx,Group Name=xxxxx,
       Access Permission=-rw-r--r--,
       Last Modified=29Sep2017:09:16:16,
       File Size (bytes)=1680

 RULE:     ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0                      
 1         HEADER RECORD*******LIBRARY HEADER RECORD!!!!!!!000000000000000000000000000000  

 2   CHAR  SAS     SAS     SASLIB  7.00    R 3.0.2.                        29SEP17:09:16:16
     ZONE  54522222545222225454442232332222523232302222222222222222222222223354533333333333
     NUMR  3130000031300000313C92007E000000203E0E200000000000000000000000002935017A09A16A16
 3         29SEP17:09:16:16                                                                
 4         HEADER RECORD*******MEMBER  HEADER RECORD!!!!!!!000000000000000001600000000140  
 5         HEADER RECORD*******DSCRPTR HEADER RECORD!!!!!!!000000000000000000000000000000  

 6   CHAR  SAS     DF_DUMMYSASDATA 7.00    R 3.0.2.                        29SEP17:09:16:16
     ZONE  54522222445454455454454232332222523232302222222222222222222222223354533333333333
     NUMR  3130000046F45DD9313414107E000000203E0E200000000000000000000000002935017A09A16A16
 7         29SEP17:09:16:16                                                                
 8         HEADER RECORD*******NAMESTR HEADER RECORD!!!!!!!000000000500000000000000000000  

 9   CHAR  ........COMPANY                                                 ........        
     ZONE  00000000444544522222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222220000000022222222
     NUMR  020008013FD01E900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

 10  CHAR  ....................................................................MEASURE     
     ZONE  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000444555422222
     NUMR  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000802D51352500000

 11  CHAR                                              ........        ....................
     ZONE  22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222000000002222222200000000000000000000
     NUMR  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000

 12  CHAR  ................................................NUM                             
     ZONE  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000045422222222222222222222222222222
     NUMR  000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000803E5D00000000000000000000000000000

 13  CHAR                          ........        ........................................
     ZONE  22222222222222222222222200000000222222220000000100000000000000000000000000000000
     NUMR  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

 14  CHAR  ............................DEN                                                 
     ZONE  00000000000000000000000000004442222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
     NUMR  000000000000000000000100080445E0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 RULE:     ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0                      

 15  CHAR      ........        ............................................................
     ZONE  22220000000022222222000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
     NUMR  00000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

 16  CHAR  ........RATE                                                    ........        
     ZONE  00000000545422222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222220000000022222222
     NUMR  01000805214500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

 17  CHAR  ....... ....................................................                    
     ZONE  00000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022222222222222222222
     NUMR  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 18        HEADER RECORD*******OBS     HEADER RECORD!!!!!!!000000000000000000000000000000  

 19  CHAR  0001    A       A ......B.......B2......0002    B       A ......B.......B2......
     ZONE  33332222422222224A000000410000004300000033332222422222224A0000004100000043000000
     NUMR  00010000100000001000000024000000220000000002000020000000100000002400000022000000

 20  CHAR  0003    C       A ......B.......B2......0004    D       A ......B.......B2......
     ZONE  33332222422222224A000000410000004300000033332222422222224A0000004100000043000000
     NUMR  00030000300000001000000024000000220000000004000040000000100000002400000022000000

 21  CHAR  0005    E       A ......B.......B2......                                        
     ZONE  33332222422222224A00000041000000430000002222222222222222222222222222222222222222
     NUMR  00050000500000001000000024000000220000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 NOTE: 21 records were read from the infile '/test/tmp.xpt'.
```

Comment: This is very helpful.  I will double check the xpt file for the corrupted file.